# Why would boto3 be unable to parse the provided xml file?

Tags: xml, amazon-web-services, boto3, saml

I'm using the boto3 library to interact with the AWS api.

I am using the `create_saml_provider` [method](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.create_saml_provider) available to the IAM client to automate an IDP configuration in new accounts.

One of the parameters passed into the method is an xml document used to configure the ipd.

When I try to call this method, I get: `error when calling the CreateSAMLProvider operation: Could not parse metadata`

Per [these Identity and Access Management Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_cn/IAM/latest/UserGuide/iam-ug.pdf) (page 718), this could be caused by 1) When the metadata file is not encoded in UTF-8 without BOM or 2) when the x.509 certificate fails to meet the requirements of a) being at least 1024 bits, or b) having no repeated extensions.

I opened the file in Notepad++ and confirmed the encoding is utf-8, so we can remove that cause from the list.

I'm assuming the x.509 certificate should meet the requirements since I got this metadata from an existing IDP configuration in another aws account.

Any suggestions on how I might debug this?

My code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import boto3
import logging

# Note that this code is inside a method which has access to an IAM client with assume role credentials from sts.  So "client" as referenced below is defined.
xml = ET.parse("metadata.xml")
root = xml.getroot()
xml_str = ET.tostring(root, encoding='utf8').decode('utf8')
print(f"here is xml_str: {xml_str}")

response = client.create_saml_provider(
    SAMLMetadataDocument=xml_str,
    Name='ipd-name-goes-here'
)

return response
```